# parse an xml file with user defined fields/values

Tags: php, xml-parsing

i'm trying to parse an xml file. Have the following structure:

```
 <verwaltung_objekt>
 <objektadresse_freigeben>false</objektadresse_freigeben>
    <geschlecht />
    <user_defined_simplefield feldname="Immobilie des Monats">Ja</user_defined_simplefield>
            <user_defined_simplefield feldname="Energie">A</user_defined_simplefield>
</verwaltung_objekt>
```

And try with this code:

```
 foreach($xml -> verwaltung_objekt -> user_defined_simplefield as $simplefield) {
foreach($simplefield->attributes() as $a => $b) {
    echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
    }
}
```

which get me 'feldname="Immobilie des Monats"' and 'feldname="Energie"'. But how can i get the value of "Immobilie des Monats"?

Thanks for any help.

Regards
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access that value by using that particular attribute, you can just use that attribute. Using the needle `(Immobilie des Monats)`, you can just compare it. Consider this example:

```
$raw = '<verwaltung_objekt> <objektadresse_freigeben>false</objektadresse_freigeben> <geschlecht /> <user_defined_simplefield feldname="Immobilie des Monats">Ja</user_defined_simplefield> <user_defined_simplefield feldname="Energie">A</user_defined_simplefield></verwaltung_objekt>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($raw);
$data = array();
foreach($xml as $key => $value) {
    if($value->attributes()['feldname'] == 'Immobilie des Monats') {
        echo $value;
    }
}

// outputs: Ja
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your only looking at the attributes:

```
foreach($simplefield->attributes()
```

So you'd need to look through node values instead, so whatever parser you're using I'd look into looking at the node value and not its attributes:

```
foreach($simplefield->nodeValue
```

Hope that helps,

Mike.